# Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')

Tags: c#, postgresql, azure-postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN5Nw.png)I am trying to connect to my Azure PostgreSql database server via Pg Admin
but in the console after the Update-Database command I get an error:

> Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')

Stack:

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')
```

Connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=postgre-azure...;Port=5432; Pwd = [Password];"
```

Another connection string with same problem:

```
"DefaultConnection": "User Id =postgres;Password=123321;Server=postgre-azure...;Port=5432;Database=[];Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
```

Does anyone know what it might be?

````
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: data source (Parameter 'keyword')
PM> ```
````

Comment: Show us your piece of code where you'r getting that error.

Comment: I would assume that you have named a parameter "keyword".
And that is either a reserved word, or the parameter keyword doesn't exist where you are trying to use it.
Like the guy above said, show us where in the code the exception is thrown. But that will likely also answer your question

Comment: the exception is thrown when the Update-Databse command in the console and when trying to save data through the controller to the database

Comment: Connection string is missing "Data Source".  See following for example of connection strings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I redid the "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Host = ; Port = 5432; Username = ; Password = ; Database = Users; SSL Mode = Require"